# spring-boot how to throw multiple custom exception in try block based on Jax-RS response Httpstatus

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, jax-rs, try-catch

I have something like this:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
public class MyCustomExceptionA extends RuntimeException {
    public MyCustomExceptionA(String message)  {
        super(message);
    }
}
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class MyCustomExceptionB extends RuntimeException {
    public MyCustomExceptionA(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class MyCustomExceptionC extends RuntimeException {
    public MyCustomExceptionA(String message)  {
        super(message);
    }
}
@ControllerAdvice
public class SomeClass  {
    @ExceptionHandler(MyCustomExceptionA.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> method1(MyCustomExceptionA  ex){
        ExceptionResponse response = new ExceptionResponse(401, ex.getMessage())
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
  }

  method2 for MyCustomExceptionB

  method3 for MyCustomExceptionC
}
```

I am making a Jax-RS rest call to get Response

```
try{
    Response response = ClientBuilder.newCLient().target("someURL").path("somePath").get();

    if (response.getStatus() == 400){
        throw new MyCustomExceptionB("some Error message") <-- this don't get thrown
    }else if (response.getStatus() == 401){
        throw new MyCustomExceptionA("some Error message") <-- this don't get thrown
    }else if (response.getStatus() == 404){
        throw new MyCustomExceptionC("some Error message")  <-- this don't get thrown   
}catch(Exception ex){
    log.error("something happened ....")
    throw new Exception("message")                  <-- this overrides above exceptions
}
```

when I try to throw custom exceptions for 400, 401, or 404 it still throws Exception from catch block.. why ?? I debugged through it and it goes to the corresponding statuscodes (400, 401, or 404), but at the end still throws Exception from catch block --> What Am I doing wrong !!

Comment: you have defined catch block for Exception class so any exception you are throwing inside try block it is being catched in catch block.This is the intended behaviour. please share example of what you are trying to acheive.

Answer (score 0):

The catch block catches exceptions thrown by code inside the try block. That is why the code inside the catch block is run after you throw an exception in the if else chain.

I'd suggest you familiarize yourself with the basics of exceptions before doing spring boot.

```
try{
  //potentially dangerous code here.
}catch(Exception ex){
  //Catches all Exceptions thrown in try block.
  //Handle ex.
}
```